# req.body is undefined mean app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I have an issue on my app. The simple way to tell you whats the problem let mme show you my code

```
var Meetup = require('./models/meetup');



module.exports.create = function (req, res) {
  var meetup = new Meetup(req.body);
  console.log(req.body);
  meetup.save(function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
    res.json(result);
  });
}

module.exports.list = function (req, res) {
  Meetup.find({}, function (err, results) {
    res.json(results);
  });
}
```

`console.log(req.body)`; outputs undefined
 `console.log(result)`; outputs `{ __v: 0, _id: 5836ce6c38485021ec195a82 }`while it should output `{ __v: 0,name:'text input' _id: 5836ce6c38485021ec195a82 }`

here is my angular controller :

```
myApp.controller('meetupsController', ['$scope', '$resource', function ($scope, $resource) {
  var Meetup = $resource('/api/meetups');
$scope.meetups = []

  Meetup.query(function (results) {
    $scope.meetups = results;
  });


  $scope.createMeetup = function () {
    var meetup = new Meetup();
    meetup.name = $scope.meetupName;
    meetup.$save(function (result) {
      $scope.meetups.push(result);
      $scope.meetupName = '';
    });
  }
}]);
```

And my model :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Meetup = new Schema({
  name: String,
  text:String,

});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Meetup', Meetup);
```

Thank you for your help. PS i use bodyparser

Comment: Are you sure that type of request is POST? and bodyParser included before all routes?

Comment: Thank you so much i didnt include bodyparser before all routes. 10q so much !!!!

Comment: Np. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

If `req.body` is undefined then you need to:

- make sure you use the [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) on the backend
- make sure you pass the correct data on the frontend
- make sure that the data passed by your frontend is in the correct place (body)
- make sure that the data is in the correct format (JSON? URL-encoded?)
- open the Network tab in the developer console of your browser and see what is transferred

See one of the answers to your own questions for more details:

- [schema error mean app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40745059/schema-error-mean-app/40745883#40745883)